Product of two strongly interacting canonical and grand-canonical ensembles
I am running hybrid MC-MD (Monte-Carlo and Molecular Dynamics) simulations. To put it simply, a nanocluster which atoms belong to a subset $A$ is sampling the canonical NVT ensemble via Newton's laws (and a thermostat). I then define a particle reservoir with a fixed chemical potential, and every now and then exchange Monte Carlo moves (addition or deletion) are performed to add a particle from this reservoir, which are from subset $B$.
I always thought that the resulting ensemble must be grand-canonical, because after all the canonical ensemble is some kind of degenerate grand-canonical ensemble where the number of particles are fixed.
I can see that this this claim is only valid for weakly interacting systems and in which case, mathematically proving the above is not so hard. But in my case particles from $A$ and $B$ are strongly interacting, and partition functions cannot be "multiplied".
I then thought about writing the partition function as such:
$$\Xi = \sum_{N_B}\sum_{s} \exp\left(\mu N_b\beta - E(N_A,N_B, s)\beta\right)$$
Where $s$ includes all states, including the possible states resulting from the interaction of $A$ and $B$. I am right to write things like that? Is there a better way?

This is called the McMillan-Mayer theory and sometimes the semi-grand canonical ensemble (be wary that for the later, this name is also used to describe a system with fixed total number of particles and varying $N_A$, $N_B$). But for example in osmosis computations; the kind of expression you wrote is exactly the one used.
Usually, you would write it in the more evocative form:
$${\Xi}_{MM}(\mu_B, N_A, T, V)=\sum_{N_B=1}^{\infty}e^{\beta\mu_BN_B}Z(N_B, N_A, T, V)$$
where $Z$ is the canonical partition function at fixed $N_A$ and $N_B$. This is simply the usual Legendre transform between ensemble.
See for example "McMillan-Mayer theory of solutions revisited: Simplifications and extensions.".

Amazing, I had a look at the preprint and it contained everything I was looking for, it seems that I had a somewhat ok intuition after all.
